# Moving a Sprite Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

What I'm trying to do is moving a sprite in a random direction or a random point and have it continue moving - with the affects of physics. I tried moving a sprite to a random point and although it worked, it just stopped if the random point was in the middle of the screen. I'm just hoping for the basics so any code/help from someone would be helpful. Also if you think theres a post already on this, can you list the hyperlink? I spent some time researching and I couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question too vague. Can you be more specific? What *exactly* isn't working? Can you provide the code? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to improve your question so it can be more easily answered. Just edit your question until you're satisfied!

Answer (score 1):

See [SKPhysicsBody](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html) and methods like `applyImpulse`.

In short, you create and configure an `SKPhysicsBody`; assign it to the sprite; and then apply force vectors to the body. Procedural example:

```
let sprite = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
sprite.physicsBody.friction = 0.2
sprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0.75
sprite.physicsBody.mass = 0.5
sprite.physicsBody.applyImpulse(CGVector(1, 1))
```

Much of this you can configure declaratively, rather than procedurally, with the SpriteKit scene editor in Xcode.